# Format My Sqlite Code by python sqlite3 and VScode

Tags: python-3.x, vscode-extensions, sqlite3-python

When I use Sqlite3 in python I want to arrange my code and color it so that it helps me to understand it and find my mistakes. I use VSCode code editor and also Extintion Python installer.
any help, this Photo to my problem, It shows that the code inside c.execute("") is all orange and I need help with formatting
[image]

I try to format my code inside function excute